# Execute stdout results

Tags: command-line, exec

Is there a way to actually execute results from a shell command, instead of using them as arguments to another command?

For instance, I'd like to run '--version' on all executables in a folder, something like:

```
ls /usr/bin/ | --version
```

I've found a way using find/exec:

```
find /usr/ -name valgrind -exec {} --version \;
```

But I'd like to do it with ls.  I've search for over 45 minutes and can't find any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
printf '%s\n' /usr/bin/* | while IFS= read -r cmd; do "$cmd" --version; done
```

Comment: I'm getting a permission denied error, even when I run it as root :(

Comment: @Jex_and_Izzy Then you have a file in `/usr/bin` that isn't executable, or that is a directory.

Comment: You are right Gilles, was wrong on my end.  Thanks

Comment: This is not using ls as requested.

Comment: @user1133275 and that is [a good thing](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/22222). Granted, probably won't be an issue in `/usr/bin` but you never know and, in any case, `ls` isn't the right too for the job.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to execute every executable file in a certain directory with a `--version` option, try this one-liner (using /usr/bin as the example directory):

```
for f in /usr/bin/*; do [ -x "$f" ] && $f --version; done
```

Comment: This worked also.  Thank you.  I'd up-vote it but I don't have enough rep points :(

Answer (score 1):

[perl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/perl) and [bash](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash);

```
ls -1 | perl -pe 's/\n/ --version;\n/g' | bash
```

or [xargs](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs);

```
ls -1 | xargs -I {} bash {} --version;
```

Comment: `$ ls -1 | xargs -I{} {} --version` output is : `xargs: {}: No such file or directory`

Comment: No, same thing hapenned

Comment: The first suggestion works, although I receive a "bash: line 2: --version: command not found" error after each output

Comment: @user1133275 First works, second still doesn't

Comment: @Jex_and_Izzy I'd need a more specific example to reproduce and correct the issue you are having with the second one.

Comment: @user1133275 I have a test folder which contains a 'make' executable and a 'valgrind' executable.  When I run the second command, the output is:

make-4.2.1: make-4.2.1: cannot execute binary file
valgrind: valgrind: cannot execute binary file

Answer (score 0):

to reevaluate shell output as shell input, use `eval`.

```
eval "$(your command here)"
```

Comment: We should note that `eval` must be used with care, at least sanity check the `eval` input first (And welcome back @mikeserv).

Comment: @cuonglm - just stopping by. I have less time even than before for this stuff lately. I've been homeless since my house burnt down last month

Comment: Ops, I'm sorry about that, hope you will be better soon.